# Слетели стили админки в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Ребята, всем привет! Возникла такая проблема: в некоторых браузерах слетают стили админки, и все выглядит криво. Переустановил wordpress - помогло, но не надолго, через некоторое время снова слетело. В интернете такой проблемы не встречал, может из вас кто сталкивался? Спасибо всем прочитавшим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть что-то не подгружается с сервера.

Стоит посмотреть нет ли 404 ошибок при получении css.

Желательно посмотреть название вашего сайта, какое оно было при установке, наверняка не localhost, это тоже важно.

Также стоит обновить страницу сбросив ее кэш Cntrl + F5.

Неплохо работать как минимум из win7, а не xp.

Comment: Я в 7ке работаю, просто на этом компе проверял. Спасибо за советы, попробую.

Comment: Юрий, ваш совет помог. Я перемещал файл common.css, но после перезагрузки страницы ничего не менялось (из-за кэша), после очистки кэша стало очевидно, что этот файл все-таки влияет на админку. Спасибо!